# Add authorization to header and access [Authorize] controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, token, access-token, bearer-token

I use Jwt token to login with .NET Core API version 3.1.

I saw token generated but it couldn't access `[Authorize]` controllers, always returns 401. I've found the way to add authorization to the headers. However, there's no detailed instructions to set up and how to use it to access `[Authorize]` controllers.

Could anyone tell me how to pass header values by using HttpClient and is there any set up else in Startup.cs? Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are adding JWT authentication to your DI pipeline in `Startup.cs` like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ⋮
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "http://localhost:5001/";
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
        });
    ⋮
}
```

- [Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme)
- [Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication)

Also, make sure you are using the Authorization middleware in `Startup.cs` like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ⋮
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ⋮
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is how you can setup the `HttpClient`:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
string token; // your token
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

- [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)

Comment: Many thanks for your directions, but it's still not working. May I miss client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization? I've tried to add it into my code, but it doesn't help anything